# Rendering conditional inputs giving error

Tags: html, angular6

I want to be able to render a different input based on a conditional. However, the inputs have to have the same ID, since they are just going to replace the other.

This is what I was trying to do:

```
<div *ngIf="true">
    <label for="id">
    <input id="id" class="x" ...etc>
</div>
<div *ngIf="false">
    <label for="id">
    <input id="id" class="x" ...etc>
</div>
```

However, my HTML lint gives an error saying that the id is already in use. Does someone a way out of this?

Comment: Your linter examines the template, not the DOM. Since the id is duplicated, it complains. Use different IDs or suppress linting on the statement.

Comment: Why do the IDs needs to be the same? Seems like if you are showing different inputs based on the value of a variable then each input has a different purpose and it would probably make sense to give them a different ID.

Comment: it's actually same input, the difference is in the display behaviour. They have the same purpose

Comment: Is it just the class that changes?